# How to generate a multiplier map for radiosity

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d, lighting

I am following this tutorial: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303205915/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/radiosity/radiosity.htm)
I am at the part where you are creating a hemicube.
I have got the code to render the scene into a texture and therfore an array.

Now how can I generate a so-called "multiplier map" for use given these 
parameters: width, height, camera location, camera direction/normal.

I want the multiplier map to be stored in an array like this:

```
unsigned char* mult0 = new unsigned char[width*height];
```

I will have 5 of these maps for each side of the hemicube.

Answer (score 0):

```
multiplier = new GLfloat[SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT];// calc multiplier map
GLfloat* row = new GLfloat[SCREEN_WIDTH];
float factor = 90/SCREEN_WIDTH;
for (int i = 0;i < SCREEN_WIDTH;i++)
  row[i] = cos(DEG_TO_RAD(i*factor));

for (int i =0;i < SCREEN_HEIGHT;i++)
  std::copy(row, row + SCREEN_WIDTH, multiplier + (i*SCREEN_WIDTH));
delete row;

normalise(multiplier,SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

Check your tutorial to normalize the map

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against using that particular tutorial for direct implementation, from personal experience.

Rather, implement a progressive refinement approach, where in each pass you select a Shooter with highest unsent radiance (initially all lights), and compute form factors from that shooter against every other patch.

This way you will have a generic CPU solution that can be used off-line (at loading time or by other tool).